Enumerating all possible lists (of any length) of non-negative integers
I would like to generate/enumerate all possible lists of non-negative integers such that the algorithm will generate lists like the following at some point
[1]
[24542,0]
[245,904609,848,24128,350,999]

In other words, for all possible non-negative integers, generate all possible lists which contain that many non-negative integers.
I have figured that the trick for a list with two numbers is to enumerate their values diagonally like this



first value\second value
0
1
2
3




0
0 (this will be generated first)
2 (this third etc.)
5
9


1
1 (this second)
4
8



2
3
7




3
6






def genpair():
    x = 0
    y = 0
    yield x,y
    maxx = 0
    while True:
        maxx += 1
        x = maxx
        y = 0
        while x >= 0:
            yield x,y
            x -= 1
            y += 1
    
gen = genpair()

for i in range(10):
    print(next(gen))

But does the same trick (or another) also make this work for lists of arbitrary length?

What is the rules for making those lists? Your question is very unclear, please provide more details.

Please qualify "all possible non-negative integers"

@SIGHUP https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number including 0

I'm sorry, but I still don't understand the question: despite the accepted answer, I can't see any mention of the SUM of the numbers in the lists. Could you please reqrite the question so your goal is clear?

@Swifty the question does not mention sums, but enumerating sums is just a lot easier. And from there, we can generate all lists that will sum up to this number.

Oh the question was actually about an algorithm that is certain to generate any list at some time (and is akin to designing an ordering on lists)? I'm beginning to understand. As an added remark, your algorithm will only generate lists of strictly positive integers.

One of infinitely many ways to do this:
Imagine a number line with cells 1, 2, 3, and up to infinity. Now think of a binary number representation, with bits indicating if there is a "break" at the cell border. So,
1  -> [1]
10 -> [2]
11 -> [1,1]
100 -> [3]
101 -> [2, 1]
110 -> [1, 2]

Note how number of bits is the same as the sum of the list, and number of positive bits indicates the number of list elements. Code would look somewhat like:
def list_gen(n):
    res = []
    counter = 0
    while n:
        counter += 1
        n, flag = divmod(n, 2)
        if flag:
            res.append(counter)
            counter = 0
    return res


Thank you! Note: this enumerates all natural numbers excluding 0, but this is fine for me. If anyone needs 0 to occur as well, replace counter = 0 with counter = -1 both times

With a recursive helper and an ever-increasing budget, where each number costs itself+1:
def genlists():
    def gen(budget):
        if not budget:
            yield []
        for x in range(budget):
            for y in gen(budget-(x+1)):
                yield [x] + y
    budget = 0
    while True:
        yield from gen(budget)
        budget += 1

Demo:
for lst in genlists():
    print(lst)

Output (Attempt This Online!):
[]
[0]
[0, 0]
[1]
[0, 0, 0]
[0, 1]
[1, 0]
[2]
[0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1]
[0, 1, 0]
[0, 2]
[1, 0, 0]
[1, 1]
[2, 0]
[3]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 1]
...

